# Google OAuth Privacy Policy - for my website

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, policy, privacy

I'm using OAuth in Google Cloud Console and I would like to know where can I get the privacy policy aspects for my own website while using it?

Do I need to put any privacy policy from Google on my website if I am using their OAuth and where can I get it?

I'll appreciate if you give me an information on German.

Comment: Are you utilizing the Google Sign In button on your website? and that is why you need the privacy information?

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz yes. Do I need to put any privacy information for this?

Comment: It is not necessary,  websites that implement the Sign In with button do not show that, mainly because the workflow or how it works, when pressing the button they would be taken to the consent screen to allow or revoke access and they can revoke as they pleased. There are some guidelines that are important that I can add as an answer.